# Does anyone know what this is called on Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I want to figure out what this is called on visual studio.

I am trying to develop a small program that shows different lists depending on the time. This list references a database

I am trying to change the list that appears when i right click the program on the background task. Similar to this example where i [right click outlook's background app and receive a list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgol2.png)

Comment: That's called _taskbar notification area_,  and the "list" is a menu, so it would be _taskbar notification area menu_?. I don't get why VS would give it a name.

Comment: On a Windows API level, you simply get a message posted to your (hidden) window when somebody interacts with the icon (clicks it, right-clicks it, double-clicks it, etc.) - you can then do whatever you want as a reaction to that, for example open a context menu. Since it will be _you_ who opens that menu, it's also _you_ who can decide at that point what menu to open. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/notification-area) how to create the icon. You can define a `uCallbackMessage` in the `NOTIFYICONDATA` structure to react on events, see the docs there too.

Answer (score 0):

This (system tray icon and its context menu) dates back at least two decades, and has been extensively covered in Windows programming books a long while ago.

You can still find legacy materials like `NotifyIcon` in Windows Forms,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/notifyicon-component-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

If you are going to write your own program, make sure you choose a proper UI framework first (Windows Forms is too old but still supporteD), and then use the equivalent control to achieve the same functionalities.